# insert all rows from table into other table, single query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table with user_ids, and other table with user_ids and other data(empty).

I want to insert all the ids into the empty table.

I know I can just do it with i.e. php script or even create copy\paste script with

```
insert into tableB values(x),(y),(z);
```

what I m interested in, though, is can i somehow use sql to create query when i dont mention each value and more like copy all selected values to new table.
like

```
insert into tableB values(select x from tableA); --not SINGLE x! 
                                                 --ALL 'X' values returned in nested query...
```

Comment: just remove "values" from your last query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look st

[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

> With INSERT ... SELECT, you can quickly insert many rows into a table
>   from one or many tables.

Syntax

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

Example

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70dfb/1)

Comment: thank you very much!
googled it, and all i found was the values(),(); trick in different variations here on SO and other sites...

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into tableB select x from tableA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Insert into tableB select col_nm from tableA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it has to be done:

```
    inset into table B select col1,col2 from table A.

    insert into table B values is used when you know the data e.g

    insert into table B values('1','','30/06/1983')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableB (x, y, z)  
SELECT x, y, z
  FROM `tableA`
 WHERE `x` = '42'
```