# Insert into one table by selecting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, sql-psm

I need to select the data from two tables and insert into one table. The same kind of the question was asked and answered many times but I have kind of requirement.

I have total three tables T1,T2,T3.
My final goal is to insert the data into table T3. I have total 15 columns in table T3. Among that 15 columns I need to fill the 14 columns data from table T2 and the data for the last column I need to join table T1 and T2 from that I need to fetch the data for that column. Please find the below query

```
CREATE procedure proc_name

BEGIN

Insert into T3(
id,
col1,
col2,
....
...
col14)

select

(select id from T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON 


(T1.somecol1=T2.somecol1,

T1. somecol2= T2.somecol2,

T1.somecol3 = T2.somecol3,

T1.somecol4= T2.somecol4) 

ORDER BY T2.somecol5  LIMIT 1),

T2.col1,
T2.col2,
...
...
T2.col14 from T2;

END;
```

Here the rest of the fourteen columns of T3 have the relation first column id.

Whenever I call the above stored procedure all the records in into T3 is inserting with top 1 id in table T1 time even though I have total 10 id's in T1.
After close observation I came to know that the reason for that is as I'm mentioning the limit 1 so it is fetch only first id every time.

If I didn't mention limit 1 it is returning all the 10 id's and the query it self is failing.

Is there anyway I can get all id's in table T3. Please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sub-queries are only allowed to return 1 row here. You need a join returning all columns to insert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122128/insert-all-rows-from-table-into-other-table-single-query

Comment: hi @jarlh, thanks for the quick reply. Could you please elaborate/explain it bit detail. In the link provided the data is selecting from single table,  but here need to select the data from multiple tables.

Comment: insert into T3 select col1, col2, col3 ... from t1 join t2 ...

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate or the comment by @jarlh (who is absolutely correct) you need to have a join between the two tables rather than selecting a value in a subquery

```
INSERT INTO T3
(id
,col1
,col2
,...
,col14)
SELECT T1.id
      ,T2.col1
      ,T2.col2
      ,...
  FROM T1 
 INNER JOIN T2 ON 
(T1.somecol1=T2.somecol1,
T1. somecol2= T2.somecol2,
T1.somecol3 = T2.somecol3,
T1.somecol4= T2.somecol4)
```

With your code as it is, you would only ever expect a single value from T1.